# Como fazer redirecionamento utilizando AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou utilizando o [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs), e preciso redirecionar para outra página dentro do meu controller. Como faço isso?

Segue o código do meu controller:

```js
meuController.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.save = function(){
        $scope.tasks.push({
            'name': $scope.title
        });
        //redirecionar aqui. Como ???
    };
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de começar, todo o código abaixo está funcionando em: http://jsbin.com/roqil/edit

Para ter o controle de redirecionamento de páginas você precisa seguir alguns passos antes.

## Referenciar as bibliotecas de roteamento do AngularJS

Referencie o módulo `ngRoute` no seu html:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

### Modularizar seu App

Só é possivel controlar o roteamento da página com um aplicativo modularizado, crie seu módulo referenciando o `angular-route` dessa forma:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
```

E na tag `<html>` adicione :

```
<html ng-app='app'>
```

A variavel `app` é global e nela você pode chamar `services`, `factories`, e métodos de configuração.

Vamos adicionar um `factory` de tasks apenas para garantir que os `controllers` estão usando a mesma lista de tasks. Conseguinte, os dois controllers, um para a view de `Detalhes` e outro para `Listagem`:

```
/*1*/   app.factory("TaskFactory",function(){  
/*2*/     var tasklist =  [              
/*3*/        {name:"terminar meu app",id:0}, 
/*4*/        {name:"comprar presente para minha irmã",id:1}
/*5*/        ]; 
/*6*/          return{
/*7*/            get : function(){
/*8*/            return tasklist;
/*9*/          }
/*10*/       };
/*11*/   });
/*12*/    app.controller('TaskListCtrl', function ($scope,TaskFactory) {
/*13*/      (function(){$scope.tasks=TaskFactory.get();})();
/*14*/    });
/*15*/    app.controller('TaskDetailCtrl', function ($scope,TaskFactory,$routeParams) {
/*16*/      (function(){$scope.task=TaskFactory.get()[$routeParams.taskId];})();
/*17*/    });
```

Detalhes das Linhas:

Linha 1 - Criando a `factory`

Linha 3 - Vamos utilizar o `id` da task para chama-la da `view` de listagem para detalhes

Linha 6 - Retornando um método para chamar a lista de tasks do `factory`

Linha 12 - Criando o `controller` `TaksListCtrl` que está recebendo por argumento o `$scope` e `TaskFactory` que é o factory. Tem que ser o mesmo nome chamado no argumento e registrado no `app.factory()`

Linha 13 - Populando `$scope.tasks` com a lista de tasks que retorna de `TaskFactory.Get();`

Linha 15 - Criando o `controller` `TaskDetailCtrl` que será responsavel por apresentar a task selecionada na outra `view`. O diferencial é que agora estou recebendo por argumento o `$routeParams` do módulo `ngRoute` que é responsavel por manter os dados que vc passa na `URL`

Linha 16 - Novamente estou pegando tasks do `TaskFactory` mas desta vez estou filtrando por aquelas que contém o id = `$routeParams.taskId` (veremos pra frente o porquê deste) então ele trará apenas uma task.

Poderia fazer assim também se preferir:

```
//esta forma
var tasks = TaskFactory.get();
var id = $routeParams.taskId;
$scope.task = tasks[id];

//é a maneira simplificada desta
$scope.task=TaskFactory.get()[$routeParams.taskId];
```

## Configurar as rotas em `app.config()`

É necessário reservar um espaço no html para permitir que o AngularJS manipule seu DOM

```
<body>
  <div >
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Apenas use a diretiva `ng-view` em alguma tag `<div>` e pronto, nao precisa referenciar controllers ou algo do tipo, isso será registrado em `app.config()` com a seguir:

```
/*1 */   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
/*2 */       $routeProvider.when('/',{
/*3 */           template: 'Lista de Tasks:'+
/*4 */             '<div >'+
/*5 */           '<div ng-repeat="task in tasks">'+
/*6 */         '{{task.id}} - {{task.name}}'+
/*7 */           '<div><a ng-href="#/{{task.id}}">detalhes</a>'+
/*8 */       '</div></div>'+
/*9 */     '</div>',
/*10*/            controller: "TaskListCtrl"
/*11*/          }).
/*12*/        when('/:taskId',{
/*13*/            template: 'Detalhes da Task {{task.id}}:'+
/*14*/              '<h4>Nome: {{task.name}}</h4>'+ 
/*15*/              '</div>'+'<a ng-href="#/"> Voltar</a>',
/*16*/            controller: "TaskDetailCtrl"
/*17*/          }
/*18*/        ).otherwise({redirect:'/'});
/*19*/    });
```

O que o código acima faz é:

Linha 1 - invoca o método `config` do módulo passando uma `function` que recebe o `$routeProvader`

Linha 2 - No `$routeProvader` você tem os métodos `when()` e `otherwise()` , cada um recebe um objeto com as propriedades de roteamento, por exemplo:

```
when("/url que vc deseja",{
  template: "aqui vai o html que será renderizado dentro de ng-view"
  controller: "aqui o nome do controller correspondente àquela url"
});

otherwise({redirect:"/"}) //quer dizer que se nao for nenhuma das url registradas,
// redirecionara para a principal
```

No primeiro `when()` estou passando que caso nao tenha parametros, chamará aquele template utilizando o "TaskListCtrl". Se o template for muito grande, é recomendado guardar ele em outro arquivo e chama-lo assim `{templateUrl:'exemplo.html'}` ai invés de apenas `template`

Na linha 7 estou simplesmente criando um link para `#/{{task.id}}`, o angular irá substituir o `taskId` pelo id da task.

**IMPORTANTE:** Na linha 12 o `when` está recebendo `\:taskId`, o sinal `:` indica que é um parametro, isso é necessário para dizer para o `$routeParams` que é chamado no `controller`, que ele terá a a propriedade `taskId`, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ademais, está passando o `template` e amarrando ao controller `TaskDetailCtrl`

## Resumo

Pronto, são necessários esses passos para fazer um controle de roteamento simples utilizando AngularJS
resumindo:

1. Referenciar angular.js e angular-route.js
2. Criar um módulo para a aplicação referenciando `['ngRoute']`
3. Adicionar `<html ng-app='nomeDoModulo'>`
4. Criar os controllers e factories/serivces
5. Adicionar o argumento `$routeParams` no controller que utiliza-ra deste.
6. Chamar ng-view no html assim: `<div ng-view></div>`
7. Invocar `app.config(function($routeProvider){...})` para fazer o registro de rotas (inclusive o `$location` só funciona se a rota direcionada estiver registrada aqui.
8. Chamar o método `$routeProvider.when()` para cada rota do seu aplicativo passando os parametros corretos
9. Distribuir tags `<a href="#/rotaEscolhida">`
10. Utilizar `$routeParams.qualquerPropriedadeRegistrada` conforme necessidade.

App funcionando aqui: http://jsbin.com/roqil/edit

### Update

Nesse exemplo usei o router nativo do angular, mas existe outro muito melhor que é o *Ui-Router*

Vale a pena dar uma conferida nesse link: 
[Como usar Angular UI Router? e quais as vantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29459/como-usar-angular-ui-router-e-quais-as-vantagens/29815#29815)

Comment: escreveu esse código e esse post todo muito rápido! parabéns.

Comment: Obrigado (: na verdade levei algumas horas para escreve-lo

Comment: agora que vi que o post foi feito à 10 dias, de qualquer modo, sua resposta foi ótima. faz um blog e passa seu conhecimento pra gente. ;-)

Comment: Ja tentei montar um blog, nao deu muito certo kk. Vou compartilhar meu conhecimento aqui, sob demanda das perguntas [:

Answer (score -1):

Para fazer isso você precisa modificar sua função para receber o parâmetro `$location`.
Depois disso utilizar este parâmetro fazer o redirecionamento

Exemplo:

```js
meuController.controller('Controller', function ($scope,$routeParams,$location) {
    $scope.save = function(){
        $scope.tasks.push({
            'name': $scope.title
        });
        $location.path("/algumCaminho");
    };
});
```

Se tiver mais alguma duvida pode procurar na documentação oficial do [location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location) do [controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Comment: Chamar direto `$routeParams` e `$location` só funciona para a versão `1.0.7` do Angular. Se estiver usando a versão `1.2.14` deve referenciar também o `angular-route.js`