# Como usar Angular UI Router? e quais as vantagens?

Tags: angularjs

Como usar Angular UI Router? e quais as vantagens ?

Quais vantagens a longo prazo de usar ele e não o padrão do angularjs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ele é muito melhor e mais poderoso que o nativo do angular, vou fazer um comparativo básico:

## ngRoute

- Roteamento baseado em url

  - Ou seja, apenas uma rota por tela e um controller para ela
- Não suporta múltiplas rotas

  - Todo o html deve ter apenas uma tag `<ng-view>`, se tiver mais de uma, o Angular vai injetar o mesmo conteúdo dentro de todas
  - Se um `<ng-view>` dentro de outro, ai já era, vai gerar recursividade

## Ui-Router

- Roteamento baseado em States

  - Ou seja, a URL é apenas uma *ferramenta* do roteamento e não um delimitador
- Suporta herança de rotas, multiplas e views na mesma tela

  - Você pode por duas tags `<ui-view>` na mesma página e injetar um template com seu próprio controller em cada uma
  - Você também pode colocar uma `<ui-view>` dentro da outra para rotas dentro de rotas sem problemas, e tendo total controle do conteudo injetado e comportamento de cada uma

#### Implementação

É bem parecido com do `ngRoute`:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

        $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/home",
                templateUrl: "home-template.html",
                controller: "HomeController",
            });
    });
```

#### Veja também

- [8 coisas que você precisa saber sobre AngualrJS](https://markwillcollins.silvrback.com/7-things-i-wish-i-knew-about-angularjs) - a primeira é justamente sobre Ui-Router
- [AngularJS Routing Using Ui-Router](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router) - Tutorial muito bacana pra vc ver o potencial dessa ferramenta
- [Utilizando Ui-Router](http://pt.slideshare.net/anisanwesley/angular-jumpstart-11-roteamento) - Conteúdo de um material relacionado a um treinamento que dei sobre Angular + WebAPI

Comment: Não tem como deixar a resposta mais simples e objetiva, mas se quiserem ganhar um pouco mais de tempo, abra o segundo link que o @anisanwesley menciona: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router