# Criar route avançado em Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, route

Estou tentando fazer com que meu `router`, trabalhe de uma forma um pouco diferente. Hoje ele está assim, por exemplo:

```js
$routeProvider.
when('/cliente', {
    templateUrl: '/cliente',
}).
when('/login', {
    templateUrl: '/usuario/login',
}).
when('/home', {
    templateUrl: '/home/home',
}).
when('/unauthentication', {
    templateUrl: '/utils/unauthentication',
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
});
```

Está correto, mas gostaria de um comportamento que ao passar essa rota, por exemplo: `#/cliente/data`, se ele não a encontra-se ele procura-se só por `#/cliente`, e ai se não encontrasse, iria para o `otherwise`.

O que gostaria era algo assim, por exemplo:

```js
$routeProvider.
when('/cliente/get', {
    templateUrl: '/cliente',
}).
// esses '...' não existe, só utilizei para representar qualquer coisa
when('/cliente/...', { 
// aqui pegando tudo que iniciar com /cliente, menos /cliente/get que é uma rota especifica
    templateUrl: '/cliente',
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
});
```

Seria uma logica similar a seguinte:

Data a seguinte rota: `#/foo/blah/blah2/foo2`;

1. Tentaria a rota original: `#/foo/blah/blah2/foo2`;
2. Tentaria a rota: `#/foo/blah/blah2`;
3. Tentaria a rota: `#/foo/blah`;
4. Tentaria a rota: `#/foo`;
5. Ai sim iria para o `otherwise`;

**Perguntas**

- Há alguma forma de configurar o `$routeProvider` para isso?
- Ou há alguma extensão do `route` padrão do Angular.js que possa
  utilizar? E de que forma eu o utilizaria para conseguir esse
  resultado?

Comment: da uma olhada aqui: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example na aba **script.js** tem um exemplo parecido com o teu, talvez sirva

Comment: @luigibertaco, não é bem isso que eu necessito, ali no caso é uma exemplo de como preparar as rotas para receber parâmetros, andei pesquisando mais um pouco e estava vendo que esse _route_ (nativo) do angular é um pouco limitado e estou analisando outros _route_ de terceiros para Angular. Mesmo assim obrigado pela disponibilidade em ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, respondi duas perguntas que podem te ajudar, segue os links:

- [Consumir Rest com AngularJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33843/consumir-rest-com-angularjs/34520#34520)
- [Como usar Angular UI Router? e quais as vantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29459/como-usar-angular-ui-router-e-quais-as-vantagens/29815#29815)