# Consumir Rest com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Criei um WebServices para receber consulta por string e devolver uma lista, exemplo:

**url/meuPath/luiz** - Sendo que luiz é o parametro que será passado, com base nesse parâmetro me retornará uma lista de luiz.

No AngularJS consigo: Listar Todos, Pesquisar por ID, Excluir, Alterar e não estou conseguindo passar um parâmetro como string. Segue o trecho de código:

```
reportServices.factory('MeuServico', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
   return $resource('/url/meuPath/:nome', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    queryParameter: { method: 'GET',  params: {query: '@nome'} , isArray: true,} 
  });
}]);
```

O AngularJS gera a url assim: `/url/meuPath?0=%2F&1=a&2=b&3=e&4=r&5=t&6=a`

Como ele gerou dessa maneira o AngularJS descarta o q vem depois do "?" e acaba caindo no serviço para listar todos.

OBS: se eu alterar o `/url/meuPath/:nome` para `/url/meuPath/nome` a consulta é feita corretamente passando o nome da variável e não o valor.

**Solução**

O meu erro ocorria pelo seguinte:

Quando eu chamava o service estava fazendo assim:

`MeuServico.Query("Amarelão");`

Sendo que eu deveria chamar assim:

`animal.nome = "Amarelão";`

`MeuServico.Query(animal);`

Fazendo dessa maneira o service consegue acessar os serviços do service sem gerar a URL como se o parâmetro fosse um array

Comment: Recentemente eu fiz uma série de slides para um curso aqui na empresa que era justamente sobre isso: **Integração com Angular e WebAPI**. Ao fim do curso postei os slides no Slideshare, dá uma olhada, pode ser útil. http://pt.slideshare.net/anisanwesley/angular-jumpstart-1-introduo-38460785 Na descrição deste, contêm os outros slides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi exatamente o problema do seu código. Reproduzi o seu código no Plunker com algumas alterações:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sTc7jcRXvIsth5Ht0mZR?p=info

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('MeuServico', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/url/meupath/:nome', null, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
    queryParameter: { method: 'GET',  params: {query: '@nome'} , isArray: true}
  });
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MeuServico) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.enviar = function() {
    $scope.name = 'Yuri';
    MeuServico.queryParameter({
      nome: 'yuri',
      grupo: 'programadores'
    });

    MeuServico.query({
      nome: 'yuri2',
      grupo: 'html'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: O problema ocorria na forma como eu estava passando o parâmetro para o service. Por exemplo: Pesquisar um animal pelo o nome. Deveria ficar assim: `animal.nome = "Amarelão";` e quando eu fosse passar eu passaria `animal' para o service e no service eu iria esperar o atributo `@nome`. O erro ocorria pq estava tentando chamar o service já passando o valor do nome diretamente.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o problema está em

```
queryParameter: { method: 'GET',  params: {query: '@nome'} , isArray: true,}
```

O parametro nome não é um array, portanto deveria ser

```
queryParameter: { method: 'GET',  params: {query: '@nome'} , isArray: false}
```