# Tela de Login com Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Boa noite, estou com problemas para fazer a tela de login em minha aplicação

### Index.html

```
<body>
<div ng-include"'dashboard.html'"></div>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Se eu colocar o formulário de `login` dentro do `index.html` vai mostrar tudo junto com a `dashboard` e a `ng-view`, e eu quero que mostre apenas a tela de `login` e quando autenticar o usuário, redirecionar ele para a `dashboard` com o `ng-view`

### NG-VIEW

```
angular.module("app").config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider.when("/Cliente", {
templateUrl:"Cliente.html",
controller :"ClienteController"
});
$routeProvider.when("/Corretor",{
templateUrl:"Corretor.html",
controller:"CorretorController"
});
$routeProvider.when("/NovoContrato",{
templateUrl:"NovoContrato.html",
controller:"ContratoController"
```

Eu poderia colocar o `ng-view` dentro da `dashboard` mas ai teria que duplicar o `<HEAD>` do `index` na `dashboard`...

Alguém teria outra solução??

Comment: O dashboard.html só pode ser visto depois do login? Se sim, poderia criar uma rota para login e outra para dashbord e remover o include e deixar apenas a ng-view. Para aceder ao dashboar só com login, veja como fazer isso utilizando o "resolve", veja também sobre ui-route,

Comment: Cara eu costumo utilizar o conceito de master page. utilizando o ui.router você pode aplicar o mesmo, assim da para utilizar uma master p/ o sistema e o login separado.

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser layouts flexiveis o ideal é mander o index.html com o menos de html possível. Como **ngRoute** permite apenas uma **ng-view** acaba sendo necessário mesmo repetir os layouts de header e footer em outros templates.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .when('/dashboard', {
      templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/login'
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script id="header.html" type="text/ng-template">
    Layout Header
  </script>
  <script id="footer.html" type="text/ng-template">
    Layout Footer
  </script>
  <script id="login.html" type="text/ng-template">
    Tela de Login
    <a href="#/dashboard">Ir para dashboard</a>
  </script>
  <script id="dashboard.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
    Conteudo do Dashboard
    <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Se quiser uma solução mais flexível você substituir o ngRoute pelo [ui-router](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29459/como-usar-angular-ui-router-e-quais-as-vantagens%20Como%20usar%20o%20angular%20ui%20router)